# Future and await no wait for flutter response

Tags: laravel, flutter

Let's see if someone can help me:
I am working with my own API, flutter and GETCONNECT.
I have noticed that if a query to the API takes more than 3 secs approx to respond, the response comes null and does not wait (does not do the await).

I have simplified all the code to be able to show it. If the API takes less than 3sec to respond, it makes the response, if it takes longer, it returns null.
If I connect to the API from another place it responds correctly.
I attach the code of the screen, the controller, the provider and the API.
Any suggestions? Thanks

SCREEN

```
class UtilsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  UtilsController con = Get.put(UtilsController());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: MyAppBar(
          title: 'Utils',
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: MyBottomNavigationBar(),
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.60,
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => con.mandarFuture(),
              style:
                  ElevatedButton.styleFrom(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15)),
              child: const Text(
                'GO FUTURE',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

CONTROLLER

```
class UtilsController extends GetxController {
  UsersProvider usersProvider = UsersProvider();
  void mandarFuture() async {
    ResponseApi responseApi = await usersProvider.prueba();
    print('responseApi: ${responseApi.toJson()}');
  }
}
```

PROVIDER

```
class UsersProvider extends GetConnect {
  String url = Environment.API_URL + 'api';
  User user = User.fromJson(GetStorage().read('user') ?? {});

  Future<ResponseApi> prueba() async {
    Response response = await get('${url}/prueba',
        headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'});

    if (response.body == null) {
      Get.snackbar('Error', 'No se pudo actualizar la información');
      return ResponseApi();
    }
    if (response.statusCode == 401) {
      Get.snackbar('Error', 'No estas autorizado');
      return ResponseApi();
    }
    
    ResponseApi responseApi = ResponseApi.fromJson(response.body);
    return responseApi;
    
  }
```

API

```
public function prueba(){

        
        for ($i=0; $i < 1000000000; $i++) {
            # code...
        }
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Mandangax! Prueba',
            'data' => '',
            'success' => true
        ]);
}
```

Comment: Can you inclide the get method too?

Comment: @KaushikChandru Which one do you mean? It's all included in the question

Comment: Try adding a timeout to the request

Comment: Maybe it is because it is used in a Stateless widget? Maybe worth a try to convert your Stateless widget to Stateful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a FutureBuilder.

Something like this:

```
FutureBuilder(future: con.mandarFuture(), builder: (context, snapshot) {
   if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
   }

   if (!snapshot.hasData) {
       return Text("No data from future");
   }

   final data = snapshot.data;


   return Center(
          child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.60,
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => doWhateverTheButtonHasToDo(),
              style:
                  ElevatedButton.styleFrom(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15)),
              child: const Text(
                'GO FUTURE',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            );
    )
}
```

Comment: It does exactly the same, if the query takes more than 3secs approx it does not wait and returns null.